# Display Json Data From URL to HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i want to display json data from online URL to HTML table?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in data.items) {
            output+="<li>" + data.items[i].Id + " " + data.items[i].name + "--" + data.items[i].old+"</li>";
        }

        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
  });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

how i can change test.json with online URL ?
its doesn't show any result can you please help me

Comment: please write some code, which you have tried yet

Comment: please find my updates

Comment: Try attaching an error handler and see what it says. It's likely either a parsing error (bad JSON) or a network error (bad url).

Comment: "test.json" should be in same domain

Comment: Did you check this link? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/. Example with online url works fine

Comment: the URL is xml not json

Comment: i need it json format